# React.js accordion with save and cancel buttons

Tags: reactjs, accordion

I am new to React.js and I will like to build a jsx page that looks like the image below. Each item when clicked on the top will have a section that will slide down and have a save and cancel button. There will be the same fields for a form in each section for different category
I have no idea how to start this? Has anyone done this before? Some directions will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution for what you are asking must have a lot of code to post here, but just Google it a little, and you will find many examples about how to achieve this.

Sorry if I do not post your ideal answer to your question, but you will find more productive if you dedicate more time to learn how to do this code in React.js than just to ask for the solution.

Here is some links:

https://reactjsexample.com/tag/accordion/

https://github.com/kunukn/react-collapse

https://alligator.io/react/react-accordion-component/

Good luck!

Comment: I have seen all the links you posted and it does not answer my question. If I know what to do I won't have posted the question here. I am just looking for ideas and not asking anyone to post the code for me. I know it will be a lot  of code. Just some directions that's all. Especially the save and cancel buttons.

Comment: Ok. If you want to focus on the `save` and `cancel` buttons inside a form, then you must to code the Accordion Components and after a component that contain the form fields and the buttons required. After that you must to use these components inside the content section of the accordions.

Comment: So are you saying make Items one to 4 different components i.e (4 components in all). Each component will have its form including the save and cancel buttons then include all 4 components in the accordion?

Comment: It depends, if the 4 components will have the same elements, or just change in small pieces, the better idea is implement one single component, and through `props` pass the changed data or design a mechanism to show the specific data on each case. The thing is 4 accordions have a form with save an cancel button, so this is the common piece between the 4 accordions.